# How to prove this formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to know how to prove this:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan\left( \frac{x}{k^2+a} \right)
 = \pi \left\lfloor \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rfloor
    + \arctan\left( \frac{x}{b^2} \right)
    - \arctan\left[ \tanh\left( \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{x}{b} \right)
                    \cot\left( \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} b \right) \right]
$$

for $0 \le a, b = \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - a}$.

At least in the special case $x=1$,$a=0$

Thank you ..

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613670/prove-this-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-dfrac1n21-right-arctan-l

Comment: For the case $a=0$ and $x=1$, there is [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/128515).

Comment: How is this a duplicate of [*that* question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/613670)? In particular kong asks for $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\arctan\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$$ which is asked in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/128357).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\displaystyle u + iv = \pi\sqrt{a+ix} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{x}{b} + ib\right)$ and follow nearly exactly the same step as in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613731/59379), you get

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{k^2+a}\right) 
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan v}{\tanh u}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v}{u}\right) + \pi N\\
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{b^2}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt{2}{b}}\right)\cot\left(\frac{\pi b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) + \pi N
\end{align}$$
for some integer $N$. The only thing left is to figure out what $N$ is...